# Import product with magento 1.4 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, export, importexport, magento-1.4

In my shop I have more `6000 products`, but my magento shop using `Magento 1.4.1` version.

*How can I move/migrate all products with images to my new `magento shop 1.9`?*

When I tried mage export file, I have message:

> Internal server error HTTP 500

please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are doing well.

First and for most thing i would to say is that as your trying to import 6k product in one go which won't be possible. If you wish you want to import the products in one go for that you are required to write the script.

Another option for you is that you are required to divide the total number of products in different parts like 1000 * 6 = 6000. And then you can import the product to your magento store 1.9 using below given link. Please, Make sure you all the given steps in that link.

[Help for Bulk Product Import in Magento](http://www.mootpoint.org/blog/magento-bulk-product-import-images/)

Hope this will make you day !!!

Cheers !!! :) :P

Comment: thanks, but if i get error, you can make export/import? you can help me?

Comment: Yes sure i will help you out if face any errors ? But please make sure you follow each and every steps which are given in the link above and then let me know if still face any problems.